# How to pass console arguments to application in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following line in a batch file.

`java Client "127.0.0.1" 9876`

It contains the name of my java class and two arguments. My application requires these arguments to run properly.

Is there any way to pass these arguments when running the application in eclipse? It would make debugging a lot easier. Of course I could resolve the problem by using the values of the arguments in the code but I'm curious.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Instead of just hitting the "Run" icon, select the dropdown box next to it, and choose "Run Configurations". Find your application (or create a Run Configuration for it) and put the command line arguments in the "Arguments" tab. See the docs for more information. It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jon, how can I pass the VM arguments by code? so I can put the arguments in a property file and retrieve them in the code

Comment: @JadChahine: I'm not sure what you mean - by the time your code is running, the VM arguments have already been used... unless you have a bootstrapper which reads the VM arguments and then starts *another* VM with your real program.

Comment: Please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217062/how-to-read-vm-arguments-from-property-file-in-eclipse

Answer (score 17):

See the run configurations. You can specify arguments. You can even prompt the user for arguments, along with defaults:

```
${string_prompt:host:127.0.0.1} ${string_prompt:port:9876}
```

The first prompt is host, with default value 127.0.0.1 filled in. Second pop-up has the prmpt port, with 9876 filled in

Comment: Ability to prompt the user for arguments is really what I'm looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Check the docs, iirc there are wild cards for which eclipse pops up prompt dialogs

Answer (score 11):

1. Right-click on your project.
2. Go to **Debug As > Debug Configurations** or **Run As > Run Configurations**.
3. Click the tab that says **Arguments**.
4. Enter in your **Program Arguments**
5. Click **Apply** or **Debug**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Want to add something like, how to add multiple parameters.

1. Right-click on your project.
2. Debug > Debug Configurations
3. Go to Arguments tab.
4. Enter in your Program Arguments, each separated by a new line. (e.g 3 arguments in attached image)
5. Click Apply or Debug

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

From "Run" go to debug/run configurations. Click the tab called "Arguments". You can give the program arguments there.

Answer (score 3):

Run configurations > Arguments tab. Just put `"127.0.0.1" 9876` in the program arguments.

Comment: Is it space separated or newline?

Comment: Space, i.e. the program name, space, the arguments.

Comment: Thanks. I confused with Swamy's answer in the same thread. Just below to yours

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think if you do what he suggested you'll get the same result (his newlines will become spaces).

Answer (score 1):

this work for me, in public static void main method.

```
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    int port_com = 2;
    boolean debugMode = true;
    int socket = 6789;
    HasarMain hasarMain = new HasarMain();

    // Check if a command line argument exists
    if(argv.length != 3){
        System.out.println("Missing, Port - socket - debugMode!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    port_com = Integer.parseInt(argv[0]);
    socket = Integer.parseInt(argv[1]);
    debugMode = Boolean.parseBoolean(argv[2]);
```

**Run-> Run Configurations->Arguments->Enter your arguments separated by tab->**

${string_prompt:argv:"2"    "6789"  "true"}

[image: Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

Run-> Run Configurations->Arguments->Enter your arguments separated by space->Apply->Run
Ensure that the right project name and it's main method are selected under "the Main"  tab under run configurations