# How to use ellipsis in for command line argument?

Tags: java, arrays, command-line-arguments

I just learned two things-
1) How to use ellipsis in JAVA i.e. how to define a variable length argument list for a function.
following is a program to demonstrate the above concept.

```
public class variable
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int d1=2;
        int d2=3;
        int d3=4;
        int d4=5;
        System.out.print(average(d1,d2,d3));
        System.out.print(average(d1,d2));
        System.out.print(average(d1,d2,d3,d4));
    }
    public static int average(int... numbers)
    {
        int total=0;
        for(int i:numbers)
        {
            total+=i;
        }
        return total/numbers.length;
    }
}
```

2) how to use command line argument. Following is a program that uses this concept-

```
public class argument
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if(args.length!=3)
        {
            System.out.println("Please provide valid 3 inputs to add them all");    
        }
        else
        {
            int first = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            int second = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            int third = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            System.out.println((first+second+third));
        }
    }
}
```

NOW... my question is how to use ellipsis in a program in which i want to give input via command line?

Suppose i want to add 3 numbers together through command line argument but my friend wants to add 5 numbers together. How do i use ellipsis in order to cater to both me and my friend's requirement?

Comment: Can you write a method that takes an `int[]` and add up the numbers in it?

Comment: This has been asked already. Please see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574543/how-to-pass-console-arguments-to-application-in-eclipse][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574543/how-to-pass-console-arguments-to-application-in-eclipse

Comment: The `eclipse` tag and "eclipse" in the title are typos for "ellipsis", aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

```
click on run menu > run configuration > arguments > program arguments
```

set parameters here

Comment: Sorry but i don't get it.

Comment: I am sorry.. i am relatively new to programming

Answer (score 0):

You don't need varargs to do this. Since the `args` parameter is already an array, let's think about this in terms of arrays. These are the steps you need to accomplish whta you want:

1. Convert an array of String to an array of int.
2. Add up the numbers in an array of int.

I suggest you try to figure out how to do each of these. If you run in to specific problems in doing so, please come back with more questions.

Comment: I used the word ellipsis intentionally... those three dots are ellipsis and i think you people misunderstood it for eclipse. What you are saying won't help i think because i am using command prompt to execute my programs. i want to provide the arguments as command line argument. What does arrays have to do with it?

Comment: @VishalKhare You put "eclipse" in the title of your question.

Comment: @VishalKhare I had no such misunderstanding. The ellipsis you refer to is what programmers call `varargs`. My suggestion is to first learn about arrays before you worry about varargs because they are very close to the same thing. In fact, as you currently have it, the command-line arguments are declared as an array: `String[] args`.

Answer (score 0):

Click "Run" menu then click "Run configurations..." then click "arguments" tab.
Just insert the 5 numbers here

[image]

After that just modify your code so you read all five inputs from args[]

In your code you can check how long the input is by using args.length which returns the length.

After that do a for loop like this:

```
    int totalSum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
       totalSum = totalSum + args[i];
    }
    System.out.printline(totalSum);
```

This will accept any length of input and sum them.