# Why do I get an 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' error?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java programming.

Can someone assist me with the following code:

```html
public class RandomSeq {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // command-line argument
  int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

  // generate and print N numbers between 0 and 1
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   System.out.println(Math.random());
  }
 }
}
```

I receive the following error message when trying to compile:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

Thank you in advance.

[1] I use a 64-bit Java 8 (Update 25) SE implementation, using a 64-bit Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (v. 4.4.1).

Comment: How do you start the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Run-> Run Configurations->Arguments->Enter your arguments separated by space->Apply->Run`

Ensure that the right project name and it's main method are selected under "the Main" tab under run configurations

Answer (score 3):

If you run your `main()` without giving argument list(`String[] args`) it will take `args` as empty.

So, the index `0` is not a valid index, since `args` is empty.

```
int N =Integer.parseInt(args[0]);// this cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

How to set argument for `main()` in Eclipse.? [Read from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574543/how-to-pass-console-arguments-to-application-in-eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

it's because args is empty :

```
public class RandomSeq {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // command-line argument
        if (args.length > 0) {
            int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

            // generate and print N numbers between 0 and 1
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                System.out.println(Math.random());
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("args is empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because You're not passing any Value So args[] is Empty..
When You are using Eclipse, go to `Run->Run Configuration-> Arguments`, Pass some value.
Your code runs perfectly fine..!!