# How to read VM arguments from property file in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

As we know, eclipse offers us a way to pass VM parameters to a specific class, look at the `VM Arguments` section in the image below:

[image]

But I am looking to pass these arguments in a different way, so I can put these arguments in a property file, and then I retrieve them in the code.

So once I call the Lesson2 class (like in the image above) from any other class , I pass to it VM arguments before running

Any suggestions?

Comment: your *workbench* will have a folder called *.metadata* , it stores all your configurations . My guess is -> you could update that file via code . Disclaimer **Never Tested!** . Once I lost my debug values , and i read those files to get back some debug parameters from those config files

Comment: Hi Jad. Could you please detail on what you mean by "retrieve them in the code"? As the vm args are used to configure the jvm reading the params must be done before initialization of the vm. So you ned an alternative launcher which reads the properties file and passes the args. On Unix you could do that with a shell script.

Comment: Hi Thomas. As in the image above, I am passing the VM arguments to the Lesson2 class because I am running Lesson2 class directly, but now I am looking to call this Lesson2 class from another class, so I need to pass these arguments from my class to the Lesson2 class because the VM arguments in the image above are useful only when I execute the class directly from eclipse and now I want to call this class from another one. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the vm argument in the form of `-DvmTest=Value`? If so, you will get that value from **System.getProperties()** as `Properties prop = System.getProperties(); String value = prop.getProperty("vmtest");`.

Comment: @ujulu : Yes I mean this form , but I am looking to set these arguments to a specific class before it executes, how can I do that?

Comment: I fear, I haven't understood your problem. Why don't you set the vm argument in the calling class? Then the system properties map is global so that you can access it from the called class.

Comment: @ujulu : thanks, i use `System.getProperties().setProperty()` ,if you put it as answer it would be better so i will mark it as best answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the VM argument in one class and access it in another class, either you set the parameter as `-Dprop=propValue` in **VM arguments** field of the *Run Configuration* or by using`System.getProperties().setProperty('prop', 'propValue')` in the code. The property can then be accessed from the map in the called class. This is also possible for applications started from command line as

```
$ java -Dprop=propValue SomeClass ...
```

or application server's start parameter (Example: Tomcat or JBoss)

```
$ export JAVA_OPTS="-Dprop=propValue"
```

and then starting the application server.

Lastly, multiple properties can be set by listing `-Dprop=value` separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JMX client (like VisualVM) and then call getVMOption(String name), see [`HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.getDiagnosticOptions()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html#getDiagnosticOptions())