# Java Execution file error

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I was working on a small project, it's about the game ROCK-PAPER-SCISSORS.

When I finished the code and tried to execute it, I've faced a problem

Here is how my console looks
[image]

And here is another picture when I tried using eclipse
[image]

Comment: Why is they command using '.'s instead of '/'s? Try `java Chifoumi/LanceJeuUntour player1 player` instead?

Comment: As for the Eclipse issue - it's expecting arguments, but you're not passing any in. Look here: http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/eclipseCommLineArgs.html

Comment: I tried you suggestion, it doesn't work :/

Comment: For the eclipse issue, I fixed it thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Try to cd into the folder that contains all of these source files, and run your `javac` and `java` commands from there. It might be with the dot notation you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

In main method add if condition, to detect if user has passed paramters. Something like this:-
  if args.length <1
    print no paramters passed.
  else
    new nameOfYourClass(args[0], args[1]);

In eclipse you can pass paramters to the main method. Here's [a link] ([How to pass console arguments to application in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574543/how-to-pass-console-arguments-to-application-in-eclipse))