# Args parameter debug command?

Tags: java, terminal

So im having trouble with the green highlighted part. https://gyazo.com/b40677c0b1ab773a693326efba0d2095 My professor wants us to display the numbers on the screen when java CardGame debug is entered in the command prompt. I emailed him about it and he said we had to make use of the args parameter in the main method. So far I have this which runs the program just fine and everything works but idk how do the the whole debug thing.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package cardgame;

import java.util.Random;
//import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Andre
 */
public class CardGame {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        // TODO code application logic here
        BagInterface <Integer> cardBag = new ArrayBag<>(6);

        Random r = new Random();
        int a;

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            a = r.nextInt(13)+1;
            while(cardBag.contains(a))
            {  
                a = r.nextInt(13)+1;              
            }
            cardBag.add(a);
        }
        int p1count = 0;
        int p2count = 0;

        System.out.println("A.Nalbandian's Card Game\n");
        System.out.println("Six Cards Selected\n");

        while(!cardBag.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.print("Player 1? ");
            int guess = scnr.nextInt();

            if(cardBag.contains(guess))
            {
                cardBag.remove(guess);
                System.out.println("Got Card");
                p1count++;
            }
            System.out.print("Player 2? " );
            int guess2 = scnr.nextInt();
            if(cardBag.contains(guess2))
            {
                cardBag.remove(guess2);
               System.out.println("Got Card");
                p2count++;
            }

        }

        if(p1count > p2count)
            System.out.println("\nPlayer 1 won with " + p1count + " cards." );
        else if(p2count>p1count)
             System.out.println("\nPlayer 2 won with " + p2count + " cards.");
        else
             System.out.println("\nGame is a tie.");

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574543/how-to-pass-console-arguments-to-application-in-eclipse

Comment: I think your professor wants a 'debug' mode which is activated by supplying a 'debug' argument. The command would look like this: `java CardGame debug`. You can determine if 'debug' is being passed by checking the `args` parameter in the `main` method. Read more about Java command-line args here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html